# how to delete the header in excel table office.js addin

Tags: office-js

I am developing an office add-in using office.js, i have added the table using it and now i want to clear the table, i tried using `deleteAllDataValuesAsync` method and this only deletes the data not the header.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/shared/binding.tablebinding.deletealldatavaluesasync.md

I am trying to find out how to delete the header in table through binding or in general too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of the Binding and Table APIs for Excel 2016 and later:

First use the [Binding.getTable()](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/binding#gettable) method to retrieve the table object for the table associated with your binding. Then call the [delete()](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/table#delete) method on the table object.

Edit: in Excel 2013 there's no API to accomplish this action.

Comment: we have drop the support for office 2013, so i am good with office2016 api now..but if you have any suggestion for office 2013 do write it.